# How to use a dynamically sized array of structs?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct

I have to make my homework. It is console application which uses an array of structs that keep information about a computer(brand, year of manufactoring, weight and inventory number). So I wrote a completely working program, but I want to use a dynamic array, because I dont know how many records the user will input.

Is there way to do this. To add new records in array until the user say n/N? Any  suggestions?

This is my version of program:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct ComputerInfo
{
    char computerMark[20], invertarNumber[6];
    unsigned int year;
    float weight;
};

ComputerInfo computerArray[300];

ComputerInfo AddComputers(ComputerInfo compterArray[], int counter)
{
    cout << "Enter mark of the computer: ";
    cin >> computerArray[counter].computerMark;

    cout << "Enter year of establish: ";
    cin>> computerArray[counter].year;

    while ((computerArray[counter].year < 1973)
        || (computerArray[counter].year > 2013))
    {
        cout << "INVALID YEAR!!!" << endl;

        cout << "Enter year of establish: ";
        cin>> computerArray[counter].year;
    }

    cout << "Enter computer weidth: ";
    cin >> computerArray[counter].weight;

    cout << "Enter computer invertar number(up to six digits): ";
    cin >> computerArray[counter].invertarNumber;

    return computerArray[counter];
}

void ShowRecords()
{
    int counter = 0;

    while (computerArray[counter].year != 0)
    {
        cout << "Mark: " << computerArray[counter].computerMark << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << computerArray[counter].year << endl;
        cout << "Weidth: " << computerArray[counter].weight << endl;
        cout << "Inv. number: " << computerArray[counter].invertarNumber << endl << endl;

        counter++;
    }
}

void MoreThanTenYearsOld(ComputerInfo computerArray[])
{
    int counter = 0;
    float counterOldComputers = 0;
    float computerPer = 0;

    while (computerArray[counter].year == 0)
    {
        if (computerArray[counter].year <= 2003)
        {
            counterOldComputers++;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    computerPer = counterOldComputers / 3;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Percantage of old computers is: " << computerPer << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    float computerPer = 0;
    char answer = 'y';

    for (int i = 0; i <= 299; i++)
    {
        strcpy(computerArray[i].computerMark,"");
    }

    while((answer == 'Y') || (answer == 'y'))
    {
        computerArray[counter] = AddComputers(computerArray, counter);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Do you want to enter more records (Y/N): ";
        cin >> answer;
        cout << endl;
        counter++;
    }

    MoreThanTenYearsOld(computerArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop using arrays, start using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Just wonder: Why 1973..2013 range?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Instead of your array, use

```
std::vector<ComputerInfo> computerArray;
```

and you can add as many objects as you want:

```
ComputerInfo c;
// read the data
computerArray.push_back(c);
```

now, `computerArray[0]` will have the info in `c`.

You'll need to `#include <vector>`.

Also, instead of `char computerMark[20]` you can use a `std::string`.

Comment: And use `std::string` inside the `vector`.

Comment: @honk you mean inside `ComputerInfo`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, to help the autogen'ed copy constructor. But you knew that.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the fact that the OP clearly stated he is doing homework and possibly isn't allowed to use STL classes.

Comment: @Code-Guru so I should automatically exclude the best solution on a (possibly incorrect assumption) that the OP can't use it? You do know what downvotes are for, right?

Comment: @Code-Guru also, where do you think `cout` and `cin` are defined? Do you see `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;`?

Comment: @Code-Guru there is nothing in the question to suggest any such restrictions. In the absence of more information, I think giving the best solution, as is done here, is the right approach.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I probably should have said something to the effect of "the OP may have restrictions on what STL classes he can use."

Comment: @juanchopanza The "best" solution can only be judged based on a full understanding of all of the requirements and restrictions of the problem. We don't have that here. IMO a more accurate answer gives a range of options when some information is missing needed to judge which one is "best."

Comment: @Code-Guru well, you're also assuming he can use direct dynamic allocation. There's nothing in the Q to lead you to believe that.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions. I was merely trying to state that multiple options should be given for the OP to weigh out given that he has a better understanding of the requirements of the homework assignment.

Comment: I apologize for the tone of my original comment. I was suggesting that you *include* further information for other options. I wasn't intending to imply that you should exclude anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Use `std::vector` instead of an array. This is a very powerful tool and certainly worth learning how to use.

2) Dynamically allocate the array and resize it as you add more items. Basically this means writing your own version of `std::vector`. This is a good way to strengthen your programming skills. You will learn what goes into writing standard classes and functions. However, I advise using `std::vector` in more serious programming because it has already been thoroughly tested and debugged.